# ZAP running parallel sessions

Tags: session, zap

Is it possible to run several sessions parallel with ZAP?
I need to scan several contexts parallel to speed the process up, because I have around 20 contexts.
I want to run them in parallel sessions and not in a singular one, so I can generate one report per context. I didn't find a way to do that directly. As far as I know you can only generate a report per session. That would also be a solution too though to generate a report per context, if possible.

I'm working with the Java API and as far as I know, as soon as a new Session is created, the running one is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of yes, but only by running multiple ZAP instances. Make sure you start them in different directories (using the `-d dir` option) and listening on different ports. How many ZAP instances you can run at once will depend on how powerful a machine you have.